# Import class from 3rd Party Library. Android Studio 3.1, Gradle 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio-3.1, android-gradle-3.1.0

After updating Android Studio and gradle to 3.1, I changed all `compile` statements to `implementation`. But when I build, android studio cannot resolve imports found in 3rd party libraries.

Scenario: Main projects imports sub-module which also import a jar file.

When I try to import a class from the jar file into the main project, android studio is not able to resolve it.

How can I import the single file without having to add the jar file as a dependency in the main project?

Comment: use `api` instead it is the new `compile` or have the dependency directly in your main project

Comment: I don't understand. Use api where.

Comment: change `implementation` to `api`

Comment: that didn't work, plus will it be possible to do it without having to import the whole library again?

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoii figured it out, the trick is to change the `implementation` of the jar file import to the `api`. I was changing if for the module import earlier. Please add it as an answer so I can select it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `api` instead, it is the new `compile` or have the dependency **directly** in your main project. Just changing `implementation` to `api` will fix the issue but you consider using `implementation` wherever possible to improve build time.

You can see the difference between `api` and `implemenation` [here](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa).

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @nongthonbam-tonthoi is correct but he does not explain why.

**Short version**

**Implementation** - hide this dependency from other modules(that depend on this module). if `B` depends on `A`, it cannot use any dep declared in `A` using `implementation`.

**api** - Make this available to other modules that depend on this module.i.e if you add say **GSON** as a dep in module `A` using `api` rather than `implementation`, all other modules that depend `A` can use **GSON** without declaring it again.

**Long version**

`implementation` is a way of declaring dependencies for only a given module. What this means is that, the dependency can only be used in that particular module. `compile` on the other hand "leaks" the dependencies to other modules so you can import and use the classes that dep brings in other modules. If you want this behavior, the new way of doing it is to use `api`.

This change is particularly targeted at multi-module  projects as it can help gradle avoid re-compiling a module during a build when it does not change.

However if you're migrating from an old project, chances are you are (ab)using compile to use dependencies declared in other modules without explicitly declaring them again.

You  can keep using `compile` but remember  that it's is deprecated and will be removed soon.

See [here](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa) for a deeper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `build.gradle (Module:app)` and change SDK version to `27.1.1`
Eg:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.projectname"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

and rebuild the project and restart android studio